# Why IsNullOrEmpty check of an enumerable part of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens?

Tags: c#, .net, identitymodel

I found a code today where an enumerable is being checked for null or empty using static IsNullOrEmpty method exposed through Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.

Now in Microsoft documentation it is listed under confidential client. My question is around the usage of it. Can this be used for any enumerable in any use case or is it recommended to use it in certain use cases? I don't find it normal to use such a functionality exposed by Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens. What could have been the intention?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.collectionutilities.isnullorempty?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest

Answer (score 0):

The extension `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CollectionUtilities.IsNullOrEmpty` was incorrectly exposed as a `public` method and will be changed to `internal` in a later release of IdentityModel.

[Conflict with Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CollectionUtilities.IsNullOrEmpty extension - Github.com](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1722)

[Make CollectionUtilities Internal - Github.com](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/pull/2416)